# ASP.NET boilerplate: IInputDTO is not triggering Automatic Validation of DTO

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have created a DTO which implements IInputDTO.

```
public class CreateUserModel : IInputDto
```

When I receive a service call on my web api layer it doesn't seem to validate the DTO as it just goes through the flow of the service method

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create(CreateUserModel createUserRequest)
```

I'm running ASP.NET Boilerplate 0.8.3

Answer (score 1):

The support for ASP.NET boilerplate has answered me that this is currently not possible. Only classes which implement the IApplicationService are currently able to do this.

[Link to issue on ASP.NET Boilerplate's issue page](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/1017)